# How can I check if every single int in a randomly generated array is even and make it create another random array if it's not?

Tags: java, arrays, math, multidimensional-array, random

So I'm trying to create a program that creates a randomly generated array with numbers between 0 and 10.
Every time a number inside the 4x4 array is odd I want it to generate a brand new array and print every array discarded aswell until it creates a 4x4 array with only even numbers.
The problem right now is that I can't understand how to fix the last `for` and make it work properly with the boolean `b` that is supposed to restart the creation of the array.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class EvenArrayGenerator {
    public static void main(String a[]) {

        Boolean b;
        do {
            b = true;
            int[][] Array = new int[4][4];
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
                    Array[i][j] = (int) (Math.random() * 11);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                    System.out.print(Array[i][j] + " ");

                }
                System.out.println();
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                    if (Array[i][j] % 2 != 0)
                        b = false;

                }
            }

        } while (b);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class ArrayGen {

private int[][] array = new int[4][4];
    private int iterations = 1;  // you always start with one iteration

public static void main (String[] args) {

    ArrayGen ag = new ArrayGen();

    ag.reScramble();

    while(!ag.isAllEven()) {

        ag.reScramble();
        ag.iterations++;
    }

    // this is just a nice visualisation

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

        System.out.print("[");

        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {

            System.out.print(ag.array[i][j] +((j != 3)? ", " : ""));
        }

        System.out.print("]\n");
    }
    System.out.println(ag.iterations + " iterations needed to get all-even array.");
}

private void reScramble () {

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {

            array[i][j] = (int)(Math.random() * 11);
        }
    }
}

private boolean isAllEven () {

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {

            if (array[i][j] % 2 == 1) {

                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    return true;
}
}
```

I think this is a good solution. Refactoring your code into structured methods is never a bad idea. I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, this is much better than what I did, I usually dislike structured methods but it's definitely more readable

Answer (score 0):

You are looping until you get an array that's all even. You should initialize `b` to be `false`, and update it to `true` in the (nested) `for` loop. Note that once's you've set it to `false`, there's no reason checking the other members of the array, and you can break out of the `for` loop.

Note, also, that using stream could make this check a tad more elegant:

```
b = Arrays.stream(arr).flatMapToInt(Arrays::stream).anyMatch(x -> x % 2 != 0)
```

Comment: or you could avoid the flat mapping completely and just go with double `anyMatch` --> `Arrays.stream(arr).anyMatch(a -> Arrays.stream(a).anyMatch(x -> x % 2 != 0));`. flat mapping is not lazy until JDK 10 if i remeber correctly.

Comment: Wow thanks, that has been very useful and it fixed my program perfectly, I didn't know that I could use stream

Answer (score 0):

What about generating random numbers up to 5 and double it? Then you don't have two check if they are even.

Comment: I want to calculate the number of iterations needed to create this random even array and put them in a diagram showing statistics

Comment: That should be pretty easy math, @axaro1: 6 even, 5 uneven, so 6/11 for each number; 4*4 = 16 numbers, the change of it being all evens is 6/11^16; so 1 in 7.6582883e15 (that's 7.658.288.300.000.000)

Comment: I'm just trying to have some fun programming to prepare myself for an exam, since I made something similar with a program creating 4 dice until they all have the same number I just wanted to make something a little bit bigger.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of your last for loop:

```
for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<4;j++){
        if(Array[i][j] % 2!=0){
            b=false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(!b){
        break;
    }
}
if(!b){
    break;
}
```

Alternatively, you could do an oddity check when you are generating the elements. Something like:

```
int element;    
for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<4;j++){
        do{
            element = (int)(Math.random()*11);
        }while(element % 2 !=0)
        Array[i][j] = element;
    }
}
```

That way you don't have to check the values, they will always be even.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class EvenArrayGenerator{
    public static void main(String a[]){
        boolean anyOdd;
        int array = 0;

        do{
            System.out.println ("Array " + ++array + ":");
            anyOdd=false;
            int[][] Array = new int[4][4];
            for(int i=0;i<4;i++) {
                for(int j=0;j<4;j++) {
                    Array[i][j] = (int)(Math.random()*11);
                }
            }

            for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
                for(int j=0;j<4;j++){
                    System.out.print(Array[i][j] + " ");
                }
                System.out.println();
            }

            for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
                for(int j=0;j<4;j++){
                    anyOdd |= Array[i][j] % 2!=0;
                }
            }

        } while(anyOdd);
    }
}
```

As you can see, I just modified the condition from `b` to `anyOdd`, so if there is any odd number, it will iterate again.

Also, you can check it when you generate the random numbers, so you avoid a second loop:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class EvenArrayGenerator{
    public static void main(String a[]){
        boolean anyOdd;
        int array = 0;

        do{
            System.out.println ("Array " + ++array + ":");
            anyOdd=false;
            int[][] Array = new int[4][4];
            for(int i=0;i<4;i++) {
                for(int j=0;j<4;j++) {
                    Array[i][j] = (int)(Math.random()*11);
                    anyOdd |= array[i][j] % 2 != 0;
                }
            }

            for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
                for(int j=0;j<4;j++){
                    System.out.print(Array[i][j] + " ");
                }
                System.out.println();
            }

        } while(anyOdd);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class EvenArrayGenerator {

    public static void main(String a[]) {
        int[][] arr = createAllEvenArray(4);
        printArray(arr);
    }

    private static int[][] createAllEvenArray(int size) {
        while (true) {
            int[][] arr = createArray(size);
            printArray(arr);

            if (isAllEven(arr))
                return arr;
        }
    }

    private static int[][] createArray(int size) {
        int[][] arr = new int[size][size];
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < arr.length; j++)
                arr[i][j] = (int)(Math.random() * 11);

        return arr;
    }

    private static void printArray(int[][] arr) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                if (j > 0)
                    System.out.print("\t");
                System.out.format("%2d", arr[i][j]);
            }

            System.out.println();
        }

        System.out.println();
    }

    private static boolean isAllEven(int[][] arr) {
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < arr.length; j++)
                if (arr[i][j] % 2 != 0)
                    return false;

        return true;
    }

}
```